# Closed applications occasionally reopen after a reboot on Mac despite no login items

Tags: macos, application-launch, macos-monterey

I've noticed this starting a few months ago, after macOS montenery 12.3 or 4. After I reboot, the applications that were open just before shutdown are reopened. However, I don't have any login items set, or anything else that would cause them to open re-open, and it doesn't seem to happen anywhere near frequently enough to warrant it being something added due to a bug, as it's only happened a handful of times.

I can confirm I definitely quit out of them, I didn't just close the window for them. This happens with applications like activity monitor, the terminal, chrome and teams.

Comment: This is an old issue - apps that were just quit right before a reboot were still in the 'open' list, so re-open again. It's a bit random.

Comment: So no way to stop or predict if this will occur then?

Comment: I've never found a way - but tbh I reboot so rarely that it's not been something I've ever actively chased for a solution.

Comment: Should you add this as an answer, or do you think it's too short?

Comment: It feels a bit short & I have no citation for it, only personal observation. I don't even know whether it pertains to one OS, or has been present a long time & still is - most of the Macs here are stuck on Mojave, only one with Monterey, which I don't use often enough to properly observe.